# The code for button.pack(anchor="center") does not work in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The `cllxk.pack(anchor="center")` code I wrote in Python tkinter does not work and the button remains below.

```py
cllxk = Button(root, text="Caps Lock Spam", width=14, command=clocks)
cllxk.pack(anchor="n")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What were you expecting it to do and what happened instead?

Comment: Your code works for me. Why do yo think it's not working? What do you expect it to do that is different from what it is doing? Also, your title mentions "center" but the code uses "n" so it's not clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

`anchor` specified how the widget is aligned in the space that has been allocated for it. The option `side` determines the space that is allocated. Since you didn't specify the `side` attribute, it defaults to "top". That means that the packer will allocate the top portion of the unused space, and places the widget along that side.

For the canonical description of how `pack` works, see [The Packer Algorightm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/pack.htm#M27) in the official tcl/tk documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You should not do `button.pack(anchor="center")`. Instead, what you should do is this:

```
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)
```

This is cause `CENTER` is a tkinter constant. This goes the same for

```
NW   N   NE
W  CENTER E
SW   S   SE
```

Comment: `CENTER` ***is*** `"center"`, so that couldn't be the problem. Many people use the string constants instead of the `ALL_CAPS` versions defined by the `tkinter` module because they did **not** do a `from tkinter import *` and would have to write `tkinter.CENTER` (or maybe `tk.CENTER` if they did an `import tkinter as tk` which is also very common).